# How to subscribe for a tag over all SE sites?

Tags: support, tags

How can I subscribe for a tag over all SE sites that I've got an account on?

Comment: You mean SE sites?

Comment: Yes. So basicly all pages from SE network.

Comment: No, all sites. Each site is separate. In fact, the only similarity is the code. The topics are different, and they all have different URLs. Pages are subsets of sites (like user pages and question pages).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Log in to http://stackexchange.com
2. Go to https://stackexchange.com/filters/new
3. - choose your tag

- name your filter
- subscribe
- save changes

> [image]

Comment: Notice that there are tags with the same name but different meanings, like the [apple] tag.

Comment: @Bra I know :)) Frank already pointed it.

Comment: Cool. I currently give it a try ;)

Answer (score 7):

Different tags are made for each site. When you see a tag with the same name on more than one site, they're not really the same tag, they just tag that topic on that particular site. For example, the [apple](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apples) tag on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags) is totally different to the [apple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apple) tag on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags).

<s>To subscribe to a certain topic (tag) on more than one site, you will have to go to each site individually, find the tag you want, and subscribe to that.</s>

There is no way to subscribe to the tag for a certain topic on all the sites across the network at the same time. You'll have to take 'em one by one.

I stand corrected, see nicaels answer.

Comment: Yes, maybe add in an example of [tag:apple] on [cooking.se] and [su]

Comment: Hmmm... I see. On technical things it would be cool e.g. for some databases. But I think I'm fine with doing it manually.
'

Comment: You can subscribe to the same tag in all sites through the filters in the main SE site, but as you said, in the case of apple you will not get what you expect all the time.